# Interact with UIProgressBar from model class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications

I have a MainViewController in my Cocoa Touch app which shows a status view containing a `UIProgressBar` view.

From the MainViewController, `FlickrImage` model objects are created and iterated over. the `FlickrImage` objects themselves interact with the Flickr API, which takes time which is why I want the user see the progress bar. The challenge (at least to me it is ;) now is to interact with the UIProgressBar (send `progress` messages) from the `FlickrImage` objects. Do I do this using a `NSNotificationCenter` or can I just declare the MainViewController as a forward class in `FlickrImage` and interact with the UIProgressBar directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to **not** have the model call anything at all, but [use KVO](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177) to observe the model, and then react to the message you get when the model updates. This is because the point of having a separate model layer is that *the model shouldn't have to know anything about how data is presented to the user*.

So create a class that keeps track of the loading of all the images (most likely you already have such a class) and do something like:

```
[imageManager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progress" options:nil context:nil];
```

Make sure that the data manager class has a declared property called progress (ideally with values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0) and when you update the value in the manager, you must use the dot notation: `self.progress = newVal;`

This is much cleaner than sending notifications from the model class. An alternative would be to register the view as a delegate on the manager. There is no clear-cut rule of thumb for when you should use delegates and when KVO is better, although there might be slightly less overhead in using a delegate protocol. Apple uses both approaches but there is a tendency to rely more on KVO, which in my opinion is a good thing.

Comment: This makes sense - I must admit that I was doing the image loading in the MainViewController. I'm moving and refactoring - this is for me as much a learning excercise than anything else - and will try and report on the result. Thanks so much for your effort to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer NSNotificationCenter, MainViewController register as observe  and update the UIProgressBar.

keeping the object MainViewController in FlickrImage and updating UIProgressBar from FlickrImage which make handling UI from model(you are violating MVC)